# sql "The data types varbinary and varchar are incompatible in the add operator."

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

```
   update UserData set strItem = cast( substring(strItem, 1, @i) + cast(cast(@Cdwid as varchar(4)) + @Cdur + @Cstack as varchar(8)) + substring(strItem, @i+8, 401-@i) as binary(400)) where strUserID = @strUserID``
```

and error

```
The data types varbinary and varchar are incompatible in the add operator.
```

What am I doing wrong?

thanks...

EDIT ---------------------

thanks for your ansver, I solved this problem, i dont convert strItem (binary) to string (varchar).

new code :

```
 update UserData set strItem = cast( substring(cast(strItem as varchar(4)), 1, @i) + cast(cast(@Cdwid as varchar(4)) + @Cdur + @Cstack as varchar(8)) + substring(cast(strItem as varchar(4)), @i+8, 401-@i) as binary(400)) where strUserID = @strUserID
```

Comment: Unless I'm reading the code wrong (kind of hard to tell), what are you casting `cast( substring(strItem, 1, @i)` to? Looks like you haven't told it what to cast to.

Comment: all of the code blocks: http://pastebin.com/HQs7bNWB , in line 69, i get this error

Comment: What about the `cast(cast(@Cdwid as varchar(4))` part?  Two casts?

Comment: ` update UserData set strItem = cast(cast( substring(strItem, 1, @i) + cast(@Cdwid as varchar(4)) + @Cdur + @Cstack as varchar(8)) + substring(strItem, @i+8, 401-@i) as binary(400)) where strUserID = @strUserID`
i update and I got the same error